# Sending follow up email after immediate open/click in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

We want to send an email follow up for openers/click any links in journey builder without any wait time for engagement split . How would it be possible? The first email will be sent immediately which is fine and without any waiting time once the email is opened or clicked any links the second email will be sent immediately without any delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with standard functionality of Journey Builder. And you can for sure not do it based on opens, as these are quite unreliable. Some clients block images, others fetch them even before email is opened.

What you will need for clicks, is a custom redirect, built using a Cloud Pages code resource.

In your email, you will need to define all the links in a custom way, utilising CloudPagesUrl function. It will need two parameters, the ID of your Cloud Page, the url to redirect to, and an eventDefinitionName, like this:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudpagesUrl(123,'event','followupEmail','redirectTo','https://www.example.com')==%%">Click here</a>
```

You should set up a transactional send in Journey Builder, with the same eventDefinitionName as in the CloudPagesUrl function.

The Cloud Page Code resource will consist of two components: Send and redirect. Let's start with send:

```javascript
%%[
set @subscriberKey = RequestParameter(_subscriberKey)
set @email = RequestParameter(emailaddr)
set @event = RequestParameter("event")
set @redirectto = RequestParameter("redirectto")
]%%
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
  
  try {
                    var email = Variable.GetValue("@email");                    
                    var subscriberkey = Variable.GetValue("@subscriberkey");
                    var triggerevent = Variable.GetValue("@event");
                    var triggermid = '123456';

                    //API to requestToken
                    var url = 'https://[yourTSD].auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
                    var contentType = 'application/json';
                    var payload = '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id": "[yourID]","client_secret": "[yourSecret]", "account_id" : "'+triggermid+'"}';
                    var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload); 
                    // HTTP POST call with parameters
                    var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult.Response + ''); 
                    
                    // Parsing the JSON Response to get the token
                    var statusCode = accessTokenResult["StatusCode"];
                    var response = accessTokenResult["Response"][0];
                    var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token;
                    var BearerT = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

                    if (statusCode === 200) {
                           
                        var jbHeaderNames = ["Authorization"];
                        var jbHeaderValues = [BearerT];
                        var jbContentType = 'application/json';          

                        //Actual email send
                        var restEndpoint = "https://[yourTSD].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/email/messages/";
                        var jbPayload = '{"definitionKey": "'+triggerevent+'","recipients": [{"contactKey": "'+subscriberKey+'","to": "'+email+'","attributes": {"subscriberKey": "'+subscriberKey+'","emailaddress": "'+email+'"}}]}';    
                        
                        var jbTriggerResult = HTTP.Post(restEndpoint, jbContentType, jbPayload, jbHeaderNames, jbHeaderValues);

                        
                    } else {
                        // block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false
                    }
                } catch (ex) {
                    Write("error message: " + ex);
                }
</script>
```

Then, after your email send code, you will need to redirect your recipient to the actual destination:

```ampscript
%%[
Redirect(@redirectto)
]%%
```

These lines should go immediately after the `</script>` tag

Comment: Thanks for your information. So can we do  that in the journey builder in a multistep journey instead of transactional send. Would it be possible for click event using wait until event feature in journey builder or event notification service? Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed possible. The payload and endpoint (/interaction/v1/events) is slightly different, but the concept of utilising a code resource for redirect is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, If you have any payload sample for wait until event (As we have to get the subscribers all information along with click status True in a data extension to filter based on click event to send further communication which seems right.) How would we do if any solution please suggest.

Comment: It is essentially an event call, and a separate data extension. You don't need to post all the data again, as the subsequent activities utilise the existing journey data. [Here](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2021/04/29/using-the-wait-until-api-event-activity/) is a good article on this topic, with much more comprehensive explanation than we can fit into SFSE. Actually, I see that [Zuzannamj](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50456/zuzannamj) shows exactly the use case you are looking for :-)

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your information.